# drag only main ul with jquery-ui?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

i have a simple nested UL's and i need to make only main UL sortable not the sub UL

example

```
<ul class="blocks-list" id="sortme">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="float-left"><img src="../templates/admin/images/icons/fugue/status.png" width="16" height="16"> Task name</a>
        <ul class="tags float-right">
            <li class="tag-time">5 days</li>
            <li class="tag-tags">Server</li>
            <li class="tag-user">You</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <ul class="mini-blocks-list">
            <li>
                    <a href="#" class="float-left"><img src="../templates/admin/images/icons/fugue/status.png" width="16" height="16"> Task name</a>
                    <ul class="tags float-right">
                            <li class="tag-time">5 days</li>
                            <li class="tag-user">You</li>
                    </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="float-left"><img src="../templates/admin/images/icons/fugue/status.png" width="16" height="16"> Task name</a>
        <ul class="tags float-right">
            <li class="tag-time">5 days</li>
            <li class="tag-user">You</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

when i used this Jquery Code

```
$("#sortme").sortable({
                    update : function () {
                    serial = $('#sortme').sortable('serialize');
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "sort_menu.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: serial,
                    error: function(){
                    alert("theres an error with AJAX");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

it made both UL blocks-list and mini-blocks-list sortable

what i need is only to make blocks-list LI's sortable not both UL's

Comment: You're html markup is incorrect. The `mini-blocks-list` cannot be placed as a direct child of `blocks-list` since it's an `ul` element. Direct children of `blocks-list` can only be `li` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a limitation in jQuery sortable, you could try [this plugin](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/) or [this one](http://www.b-hind.eu/jquery/index.php) if you don't find out a pure jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sortable `items` option to filter exactly what you need and to keep other items from being sortable.  For example `items: "> li"`.  [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-items)